# HTML Maintain dropdown selection after submit php

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a dropdownmenu in my form that load options from an array.It can loads the options fine. However after I submit the form, the dropdown menu always resets itself. It seems like the $POST['sel'] isn't getting the value after submitting. I want the dropdownmenu to display the selection after submit the form. Where am i going wrong?

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<select name="Sel" > 
<?php
$Arr = array();
//loads array into $Arr

foreach($Arr as $option){

    if($option == $POST['Sel']){
        echo "<option selected='selected'>{$option}</option>";    
    }
    else{
        echo "<option>{$option}</option>";
    }
}    
?>
</select><br>
<input type="Submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `$_POST`, not `$POST`.

Comment: oh my goodness.. Thank you :)

Comment: On that note: the reference to `$POST['Sel']` should have been throwing a notice error.  You should be watching out for this kind of error in your logs while developing, as it often will highlight problems like this.

Comment: Hmm I am using notepad++, so that may be why it's not highlighted or throwing the error. In the error_log on the server, it didn't notify this error either.

Comment: Add `error_reporting(-1)` at the beginning of your script.